# unset IFS - unexpected behaviour

Tags: linux, bash, sh

I thought it was universally agreed that `unset IFS` restores IFS to its default value.
I cannot find the reason why the following code

```
echo -n "_${IFS}_" | xxd
IFS=':'
echo -n "_${IFS}_" | xxd
unset IFS
echo -n "_${IFS}_" | xxd
echo "${IFS-IFS is unset}"
```

returns this

```
0000000: 5f20 090a 5f                             _ .._
0000000: 5f3a 5f                                  _:_
0000000: 5f5f                                     __
IFS is unset
```

in both my Ubuntu and Android.
As you can see, IFS is actually unset.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Apparent cross-site duplicate http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97481/ifs-null-is-not-the-same-as-unset-ifs

Comment: @anubhava it's unexpected that IFS is not restored to default value of `$' \t\n'`, as @tripleee 's link explains. Did you guys actually read my question?

Comment: `unset IFS` will indeed unset `IFS`. It won't be set to `$' \t\n'`. Though empty `IFS` also behaves like setting it to `$' \t\n'`

Comment: thanks @anubhava , now I get it.

Comment: @anubhava That is only true in some cases. It's wrong in other cases where it can lead to hard to find bugs if you `unset IFS`.

Answer (score 16):

> I thought it was universally agreed that unset `IFS` restores `IFS` to its default value.

This is plain wrong and there are no mentions of this in any documentations!

---

Let's search for `IFS` in [the reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html) and see what we can learn:

### [3.4.2 Special Parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Special-Parameters)

> `*` (`$*`) Expands to the positional parameters, starting from one. When the expansion is not within double quotes, each positional parameter expands to a separate word. In contexts where it is performed, those words are subject to further word splitting and pathname expansion. When the expansion occurs within double quotes, it expands to a single word with the value of each parameter separated by the first character of the `IFS` special variable. That is, `$*` is equivalent to `$1c$2c…`, where `c` is the first character of the value of the `IFS variable`. **If `IFS` is unset, the parameters are separated by spaces.** If `IFS` is null, the parameters are joined without intervening separators.

Try it:

```
$ set -- one two three
$ IFS=hello
$ echo "$*"
onehtwohthree
$ unset IFS
$ echo "$*"
one two three
$
```

Similar expansions will occur with the array-like expansions: `"${array[*]}"` and `"${!prefix*}"`.

### [3.5.7 Word Splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Word-Splitting)

> The shell treats each character of `$IFS` as a delimiter, and splits the results of the other expansions into words using these characters as field terminators. **If `IFS` is unset, or its value is exactly `<space><tab><newline>`, the default,** then sequences of `<space>`, `<tab>`, and `<newline>` at the beginning and end of the results of the previous expansions are ignored, and any sequence of `IFS` characters not at the beginning or end serves to delimit words.

Maybe the confusion comes from the part in bold.

The reference for the `read` builtin refers to this section too, so we won't learn anything new there. The other mentions of `IFS` will not bring anything new to the picture.

---

### Conclusion.

No, unsetting `IFS` will *not* reset it to its default value. There are no mentions of that anywhere in the manual. The confusion comes from the fact that the manual specifies that, for word splitting (and the `*` form of array-like parameters), an unset `IFS` yields the same behavior as the default value of `IFS`.

Answer (score 7):

I too have seen posts from people saying that if you unset IFS, that restores it to the default.  The other answers here help to clarify the story...

On a practical use basis, I would like to add that I did *not* observe the same thing on Ubuntu and Droid as the op reports. I tested in Ubuntu 18 against `/bin/sh`, and it worked as expected (like it was *restored* to the white space characters).  But, on Yocto (another Linux distro), using `/bin/sh` equates to BusyBox (like you'd find on a Droid), `unset IFS` caused it to act like it were set to `NULL`, i.e. arguments had no delimiters between them when received in functions etc.

To deal with this, I defined a "constant" `DEFAULT_IFS=$' \t\n'` and assigned IFS to that rather than using `unset`.  That method worked across contexts for me.

Answer (score 6):

Quoting POSIX / http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_05:

> If the value of *IFS* is a <space>, <tab>, and <newline>, or if it is unset, ...

This does not mean unsetting `IFS` automatically resets it to `" \t\n"`. It simply means if you unset `IFS`, word splitting is done as if `IFS` were set to `" \t\n"`.